# Generate svg defs in react component dynamically may case memory leak

Tags: reactjs, svg, memory-leaks, frontend, data-visualization

I'm working on a svg animation that needs generate svg gradient in  element dynamically in realtime as the animation going.

but it seems that the browser wouldn't free the  memory even after it
has been used or removed from the dom by React.

After hours of research I found this happens if the gradient elements has a id of infinite range(eg Math.random).

Now my question is how can I free that memory without a browser reload?

Thanks.

[demo](http://codepen.io/zhaomiing/pen/EmGpRy?editors=0010)

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <svg width="1000" height="500">
          <Tt></Tt>
        </svg>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class Tt extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.timer = null;
    this.state = {
      id: 0
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let loop = () => {
      this.setState({
        id: this.state.id + 1
      }, () => {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(loop);        
      });
    };

    loop();
  }

  render() {
    let arr = [];

    for(let i = 0; i <= 1000; i++){
      arr.push(Math.random());
    }

    return <g>
      <defs>
        {
          arr.map((randomnum, i) => {
            // define defs gradient with random id
            return (
              <linearGradient id={`r${randomnum}`}>
                <stop offset="20%" stopColor="#39F" />
                <stop offset="90%" stopColor="#F3F" />
              </linearGradient>
            )
            // -----problem solved if use i as id---
            // return (
            //   <linearGradient id={`r${i}`}>
            //     <stop offset="20%" stopColor="#39F" />
            //     <stop offset="90%" stopColor="#F3F" />
            //   </linearGradient>
            // )
          })
        }
      </defs>
      <g>
      {
        arr.map((randomnum, i) => {
          // use gradient with random id
          return <rect x={Math.random()*1000} y={Math.random()*500} width="100" height="100" fill={`url(#r${randomnum})`}></rect>
          // -----problem solved if use i as id---
          // return <rect x={Math.random()*1000} y={Math.random()*500} width="100" height="100" fill={`url(#r${i})`}></rect>

        })
      }
      </g>
    </g>
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <App /> ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

[image]

Comment: which browser is that?

Comment: Chrome 59 on Mac

Comment: then you shoud look at chrome's bugtracker and raise this if nobody else has.

Comment: thanks for you advice @RobertLongson. But i 'm a newbie to svg, i'm not sure that's chrome's bug or my code.

Comment: Hey did you find how to solve the problem?